# How to increase or decrease the width of the nav bar by using the media in CSS

Tags: css, media-queries

How to increase or decrease  the width of the nav bar by using the media in CSS
I am trying to decrease and increase the side bare width of the side bar by using media in CSS.

```
@media (min-width: 289px) and (max-width: 1100px){
  .nav .lib {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1):

First, set a default width for your navbar that will apply when none of the media query conditions are met.

```
.nav .lib {
  width: 200px; /* Default width */
}
```

Then, use media queries to change the width based on the viewport's width. You've already started this; you can continue by adding more conditions for different ranges.

```
/* For viewports between 289px and 1100px */
@media (min-width: 289px) and (max-width: 1100px) {
    .nav .lib {
      width: 100px;
   }
}

/* For smaller viewports (less than 289px) */
@media (max-width: 288px) {
   .nav .lib {
     width: 80px; /* Adjust as needed */
   }
}

 /* For larger viewports (more than 1100px) */
@media (min-width: 1101px) {
   .nav .lib {
      width: 300px; /* Adjust as needed */
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

first you have to set a default width for ex:

```
.nav .lib {
  width: 200px; 
}
```

second you have to add the specific value you want for specific media dimensions ex:

```
@media (min-width: 289px) and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .nav .lib {
    width: 150px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add one value either min-width / max-width two values are not needed unless you targeting a specific device.

For mobiles, the min-width starts from 320px for your future reference.

```
@media (min-width:320px) { /* iPhone SE*/
.nav .lib { 
   width: 100px; 
 } 
}
@media (min-width:375px) { /* iPhone 13 Mini*/
.nav .lib { 
   width: 200px; 
 } 
}
@media (min-width:767px) { /* iPads  starts from 768 */
.nav .lib { 
   width: 300px; 
 } 
}
```